# Is there an reason to call the base constructor of object?

Tags: c#, .net

I wonder if there is any reason to call the base constructor when inheriting from `object`.

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo()
        : base() // calling the Object constructor 
    {
        // Foo construct here
    }
}
```

Is there a way to inject code into the base constructor? Object doesn't seem to have multiple constructors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to explicitly call the base constructor in this situation. The base constructor is automatically called if it has no parameters. So the code is equivalent to just doing:

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        // Foo construct here
    }
}
```

`: base` is only needed if the base class needs parameters passed to its constructor.